# Replacing strings in C

Tags: c, string, visual-studio

Okay, guys, I have to write a program that forms a new string based on the given template and the given strings. The template is set as a string where it is necessary to replace all occurrences of the character '%' with a concrete string. If the template contains more characters '%' than the entered strings, characters '%' replaces strings cyclically. If no string is entered, print "ERROR". The number of strings is not known in advance. The end of the entry is indicated by a blank line ("\n").
Also, there are some conditions I need to fulfill, which are:

1) Implement char * readLine () function; which reads one row from the standard input and returns the pointer to that loaded row.

2) Implement char ** readLines (int * n) function; which reads strings that change all occurrences of the character '%' in the template. The function returns an array of pointers to the strings entered as a return value. Also, the function returns the number of values entered via argument n.

3) Implement char * format function (char * **format**, char ** **values**, int **n**); which formats the string **format** by changing each occurrence of the '%' character to a corresponding string from a string of **values** of length **n**.

4) Write a master program that, using previously implemented functions, reads the template and strings from the standard input, forms a new string as described, and prints the result to standard output.

I barely understand what I'm supposed to do so I came here to ask for help. What I did for now is the first task, but on the output I get 1 more blank line than I'm supposed to and I can't find any way to fix it. Any kind of help is welcomed since I'm really stuck here, even explaining what I'm supposed to do in some tasks, or making current code simpler is awesome. Thanks in advance. Here is my code.

EDIT: Added examples.

Input:

% be or not % be.

To

Output:

To be or not To be.

Input:

% and % make purple.

Blue

red

Output:

Blue and red make purple.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


char* readLine() {
    char* line = malloc(100), * linep = line;
    size_t lenmax = 100, len = lenmax;
    int c;

    if (line == NULL)
        return NULL;

    for (;;) {
        c = fgetc(stdin);
        if (c == EOF)
            break;

        if (--len == 0) {
            len = lenmax;
            char* linen = realloc(linep, lenmax *= 2);

            if (linen == NULL) {
                free(linep);
                return NULL;
            }
            line = linen + (line - linep);
            linep = linen;
        }

        if ((*line++ = c) == '\n')
            break;
    }
    *line = '\0';
    return linep;
}


int main() {

    printf("%s", readLine());
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: For the 2nd task, I tried to do something similar like in the first, but I couldn't really figure out how to make it so that it works. Here is what I did:

```
char** readLines(int* n) {
    char* line = malloc(100), * linep = line;
    size_t lenmax = 100, len = lenmax;
    int c, flag = 0;

    if (line == NULL && flag > 1) {
        char* linen = realloc(linep, lenmax *= 2);
    }

    else if (line == NULL && flag == 0)
        return NULL;

    for (;;) {
        c = fgetc(stdin);
        if (c == EOF || c == '\n')
            break;

        if (--len == 0) {
            len = lenmax;
            char* linen = realloc(linep, lenmax *= 2);

            size_t diff = line - linep;
            if (linen == NULL) {
                free(linep);
                return NULL;
            }
            line = linen + diff;
            linep = linen;

            flag++;
        }

        *line++ = c;
    }
    *line = '\0';
    char* temp = linep;
    return linep;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212825/discussion-on-question-by-ik4a-replacing-strings-in-c).

Answer (score 2):

At least this problem

`line = linen + (line - linep);` is UB, as code cannot use `linep` after it has been free'd in `realloc()`.

Instead calculate and save  the `line - linep` difference before `realloc()`

```
    size_t diff = line - linep;  // add
    char* linen = realloc(linep, lenmax *= 2);
    if (linen == NULL) {
       ...;
    }
    // line = linen + (line - linep);
    line = linen + diff;
```

---

OP apparently does not want to retain the `'\n'`.  Change

```
    // if ((*line++ = c) == '\n') break;
    if (c == '\n') break;
    *line++ = c;
```

I'd also recommend a *right size* `realloc()` step in the end.

Comment: Tried it now, output is still the same.

Comment: Is it, though? I thought it'd only be UB if you dereference it?

Comment: @Ik4a getting rid of the UB won't get rid of the newline. It isn't good to have UB in your code, ever, though. So it's good that you got rid of it.

Comment: @LouisCloete "I thought it'd only be UB if you dereference it?" De-ref  is UB yet even reading/copying the free'd pointer's value is UB - although many platforms do not do anything nasty.  For those odd cases where code needs to remember a free'd pointer value, convert it to a `uintptr_t` integer and save that before freeing.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read a line until `EOF` or `'\n'`, but without the newline in your string, you need to do this:

```c
for (;;) {
    c = fgetc(stdin);
    if (c == EOF)
        break;

    // realloc logic comes here

    if (c == '\n')
        break;

    *line++ = c;
}
```

Comment: Any help with the other conditions?

Comment: For a good `readLine()`, code could/should return `NULL` when the first `fgetc()` call returned `EOF` .  This helps calling code know when input is done and is distinguishable from reading just a `"\n"`.   (Advanced: return `NULL`  whenever `fgetc()` returns `EOF` due to a rare input error).  UV for getting to OP's main issue.

Comment: @LouisCloete Can you at least explain what I'm supposed to do? In the 2nd condition, as I understand, I'm supposed to make pointer to each word separately?

Comment: Give it a while, and ask a new question here if you don't make progress. That's the only way to learn.

Comment: Also, can you accept @chux-ReinstateMonica's answer? It is IMO the better one.

Comment: @LouisCloete Okay bro, thanks anyway you helped a lot!

Comment: @LouisCloete Okay so it's been two hours and I still made no progress. Hope you are still here.

Comment: @LouisCloete Whenever you can, if you ever see this again, please write the other tasks because I really can't figure it out yet, I need to study more.

Comment: For #2, try to reuse your readLine function in a loop which keeps running until something happens. Use malloc and realloc to store a char *[] to use to store the results.

Comment: Okay, I understand that but I couldn't figure out how to skip the first line and start reading from the second, and how to separate each string into an array.

Comment: I tried to make a flag system that increases every time there is \n in input, and to store strings only `while (flag > 1);` but nothing really happens and I wasn't sure why.

Comment: @LouisCloete Also, it has to be sort of self-standing function, it shouldn't be dependant on other functions to work. That is why I remade the first function and tried to loop it but it won't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212864/discussion-between-louis-cloete-and-ik4a).